# Ionic 4 : use cordova media-capture plugin in the Ionic Lab?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, serve

I am currently learning Ionic 4, and for an academic project, we have to develop a mobile app for iOS and Android.

The development of our project was going prefectly fine, and we used the `ionic serve -l` to run our app. We find that the Ionic Lab is really practical to develop, as we can have a mobile preview of our app inside the browser, for android as well as for iOS. We also really like the "live" aspect of the `ionic serve` command, as we don't have to restart the server at every change in the code.

However, as I now have to implement an audio recorder in the app, I tried the follow the documentation of Ionic available [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media-capture). I added the cordova-plugin-media-capture plugin with the following command `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture`, and installed the media-capture package with the following command `npm install @ionic-native/media-capture`.

It seems like it's working fine, but when I click on a button to try to record some audio, it doesn't work, and I get the following warning and error the Chrome console :

> Native: tried calling MediaCapture.captureImage, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
>
> cordova_not_available

I've searched for solutions online, and it seems like in order to use cordova plug-ins such as the media capture, it is needed to run the application with a command like `ionic cordova run browser`. And it seems like it's working, however I get the "browser" version of my app.

So my question is fairly simple : is there any way I can get the cordova media capture plug-in to work in the Ionic Lab ? If not, is there any other app-testing envrionment that are similar to the Ionic Lab (a mobile platform preview, fast launch, live testing...) that allows this plug-in to work ?

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, as me and my team are still learning Ionic for school, and thus are quite new to this whole envrionment.

Thanks in advance for your answers.